# Controlling mesh modifiers with animation nodes

Tags: modifiers, animation-nodes, ocean-simulation

Is there a way to control mesh modifiers using the Animation Nodes add-on? I'd like to use AN to set values for the animatable parameters in the Ocean modifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done using the "Object Data Path Output" node:

Add the node to the node tree.

Select the object whose properties are to be modified in the first input of the Object Data Path Output node.

Copy the data path from the parameter you want to animate by right-clicking and selecting "Copy data path."

Paste the data path into the Path input of the Object Data Path Output node.

Set the value of the property using the Value input of the Object Data Path Output node.

Comment: While this approach works, it appears to result in rapidly growing memory consumption when rendering animations.